# Database design for 2 1-to-many?

Tags: mysql, database-design

It's the first time here so I don't know if it's the right place to ask.. I'm not good in database design, just learning, so I'd like some advice if possible.

The case:

I'm building a really small application, a plugin, who's tables will likely have not too much records in real life (less than 50 in extreme situations), so performance is not crucial.

- The user can create n Groups. A Group should have a 'hook' field.
- For each Group, the user can create n BannerBoxes. So, a Group can have many BannerBoxes, a BannerBox can have only one group. Therefore a 1-many relation.
- There can be n languages, and the Language table is already in place and has id_lang field. The language-group relation is 1 (language)-many (groups)

I'll often have to ask the db for all BannerBoxes saved for a certain language, grouped by Group. So, first find all Groups of a language, then for each Group, find its BanneBoxes.

I've thought about 2 solutions, but I cannot decide which could be better, and since I'm definitly a newbe, both could be just wrong.

a. Group entity with [hook, id_lang] fields; BannerBox entity with an [hook] field (desides the others). So when selecting, I can join the Group table with Language table on id_lang and then join with BannerBoxes on hook field.

b. Only the BannerBox entity, in this case with both [hook, id_lang] fields. I could join with Language by id_lang and then group by hook.

I also guess that a Group_BannerBox table [id_group, id_bannerbox] would be useless since I think it's a solution for many-many relations, am I right?

So, what would you do? a. or b.?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `hook`? Is it a unique property of `Group`? (it seems to be since you are using it in `BannerBox` instead of `id_group`).

Comment: About the languages, can the BannerBoxes that belong to the same Group, have different languages? Or they should all have the same as their Group?

Comment: :) thank you all for rapid and many answers! Hook is a field of Group, but cannot be used as primary id, as far as I can say. In practice, a hook is a 'place' on a website where I can put n bannerboxes. So itself, Group could even be the only field of a Group record. In fact, Group could be just Hook instead. BannerBoxs belonging to the same Group/Hook cannot have different languages. I'm using mysql, but this is just a general bd design question.

Comment: @Stratboy so is hook equal to: max banners, left side bar, or max banners on left side bar?

Comment: @Erik: mmm please excuse me I can't understand your question. Probably being a newbe I lack some db terminology. I try to explain the real use case: hooks are a programming contruct used on the platform I'm building a plugin for. They help programmers to dynamically place pieces of html code in certain places on an page. For ex, a hook can be called 'headerhook', 'sidebarhook', etc.. In my case, the platform user will select a hook and then will create and assign bannerboxes (html boxes for showing banner slideshows) to that hook > that means, for ex: 'place those boxes on the home's sidebar'.

Comment: Gotcha, in that case I think the hook on the group table should be a FK to a 'hook' table like the 'language' table in my answer. Also if my answer is helpful please accept it or let me know what I need to do to improve it

Answer (score 2):

- Create a `User` table with a `UserId` PK and any other user related fields.
- Create a `Language` with a `LanguageId` PK and the name of the language.
- Create a `Group` table with a `GroupId` PK, `UserId` FK, `LanguageId` FK, Hook? and any group specific fields.
- Create a `BannerBox` table with a `BannerBoxId` PK, `GroupId` FK, and any other Banner Box specific fields

This will let you get all the information you need assuming that languages are consistent for a group.

I don't know what your Hook field is so answering @ypercube's comment would be helpful.  In this answer I assumed it was some sort of business logic that was relevant at the group level.

Comment: And note that `Group` and `User` are reserved (and almost everywhere reserved) keywords, respectively..

Comment: @ypercube very true.  Since the OP identified themselves as a newbie I'm glad you pointed that out otherwise my answer might have lead to frustration instead of assistance.  I included them because they were the terms the OP used and the RDBMS I am most familiar with (SqlServer) allows you to escape reserved words if you want to use them for table names etc.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks for editing my answer to highlight the column and table names.  I'll have to remember that mark down for future answers.

Comment: Yeah. All DBMS I know allow escaping, with either double quotes (the standard) or/and some other character. But it's cumbersome to have to quote every occurrence of a table. That's the only reason I kind of like plural names in tables (because of: Group, Order, User ;)